# Crawlers doesn't read my javascript appended meta tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, meta-tags

Crawlers does not get meta tag in my header appended via script:

```
document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + '<meta name="description" content="Description">'
```

This script is located in the head and appends the element fine. Tried JQuery as well. Would like to do this very first step since I will be adding dynamic data using JS reading from a JSON file soon.

Is there a proper JS code format that will not prevent crawlers from crawling my script?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having same issue.

Comment: @haha haven't solved it yet, sticked to static data for the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to javascript but to the crawlers themselves, today most search engine bots are optimized to handle dynamic content, including changes in the head element itself - of course assuming changes happen in a reasonably short time.

My guess is that you either have something that prevents crawlers from getting to your site - check the robots.txt file in the root directory of your site, or that your website data will be crawled soon, or the data is still in processing but you are checking before that happens - give it some time and it should work.

Comment: tried allowing all in robots.txt file and giving it some time but still no proper response. As you've seen on my approach above, the short script should be loaded without any problem and delay but still the insertion of that was not recognized by the crawlers ☹

Comment: tried also the approach where I add a blank meta and replace its content via script but it won't get the content replacement as well, it only recognizes the static content before that.

Comment: @KelvinBarsana if your changes do actually happen in a reasonable time and nothing is blocking robots, and you still don't get indexed then you can try a different javascript variation that does the same functionality so instead for example of adding to innerHTML you can add a meta tag using appendChildNode (which is prefered anyway for performance and code reasons). But eventually there is no way to make this work for sure other than trial and error, since this is related to crawlers and not javascript (and unless you have crawlers source code,, you can only guess and try)

Comment: @KelvinBarsana appendChildNode is mistake, its appendChild or you can use append